# Two operations in 1 list

Tags: python

I have a single list of lists

```
w = [['2', '22', '32', '44', '55', '66', '69', '94'], ['22', '24', '49', '74', '90', '113', '130', '140']]
```

From this is have to derive a new list of lists where in which :
all elements at the `even indices will have 1 subtracted from them` and `all odd indices will have 1 added to them`. So the above list will look like:

```
x = [['1','23','31','45','54','67','68','93'],['21','25','48','75','89','114','129','141']]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: once again what have you tried?

Comment: I agree with jurgenreza. The solution (or at least a reasonable attempt) isn't any harder than figuring out how to enter the question on stackoverflow. Go for it!

Comment: i tried doing:

`for i in w:
 for k in i % 2 == 0:
  x = int(k) - int(1)`

Comment: @begin.py can you stick that in the question? You are well on the way to a solution.

Comment: please include the code you have tried in the question

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> w = [['2', '22', '32', '44', '55', '66', '69', '94'], ['22', '24', '49', '74', '90', '113', '130', '140']]
>>> [[str(int(s)+(1 if i%2 else -1)) for i, s in enumerate(lst)] for lst in w]
[['1', '23', '31', '45', '54', '67', '68', '95'], ['21', '25', '48', '75', '89', '114', '129', '141']]
```

Comment: glad to see i had a correct idea about how to approach the problem. Just needed the correct way to code. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yep, using `index % 2` is the right way to figure out if the index is even or odd, but from your comment it looks like there were a few things you were doing wrong.  If you edit your question to include the complete code I can try to explain exactly what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Answers with List Comprehension have been posted. Here is an alternative using simple for loops:

```
for ls in w:
    for i, v in enumerate(ls):
        if i % 2:
            ls[i] = str(int(v) + 1)
        else:
            ls[i] = str(int(v) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what you tried, and what's wrong with it. Using a live visualizer will make this easier. And so will using a bit less data. So, [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=w+%3D+%5B%5B%272%27,+%2722%27%5D,+%5B%2722%27,+%2724%27%5D%5D%0Afor+i+in+w%3A%0A++++for+k+in+i+%25+2+%3D%3D+0%3A%0A++++++++x+%3D+int%28k%29+-+int%281%29%0A++++++++&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&py=2&curInstr=0) you can visualize this code:

```
w = [['2', '22'], ['22', '24']]
for i in w:
    for k in i % 2 == 0:
        x = int(k) - int(1)
```

First, what does `for k in i % 2 == 0` do? Well, each `i` in `w` is a `list`, so `i % 2` is going to raise a `TypeError`.

What you want here is a `for` loop with an `if` inside it. This is going to get hard to discuss with these 1-letter names, so let's give the variables better names while we're at it. So:

```
data = [['2', '22'], ['22', '24']]
for sublist in data:
    for element in sublist:
        if element % 2 == 0:
            # even index
        else:
            # odd index
```

But this isn't right, because the rule is if the *index* is even, not if the *value* is even. The way to get both the index and the value while looping is the `enumerate` function. So:

```
for sublist in data:
    for index, element in enumerate(sublist):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            # even index
        else:
            # odd index
```

Meanwhile, just doing `x = int(k) - int(1)` doesn't do anything; it just sets some temporary variable that immediately goes away. You have to put the new value back into the `list`. So, replace the inside of the loop with:

```
if index % 2 == 0:
    sublist[index] = int(element) - int(1) 
else:
    sublist[index] = int(element) + int(1)
```

You can visualize the whole thing put together [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=data+=+%5B%5B%272%27,+%2722%27%5D,+%5B%2722%27,+%2724%27%5D%5D%0Afor+sublist+in+data%3a%0A++++for+index,+element+in+enumerate%28sublist%29%3a%0A++++++++if+index+%25+2+==+0%3a%0A++++++++++++sublist%5Bindex%5D+=+int%28element%29+-+int%281%29%0A++++++++else%3a%0A++++++++++++sublist%5Bindex%5D+=+int%28element%29+++int%281%29%0A&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&py=2&curInstr=0). Step through it until you understand how it works, how close you were, and what's different.

If you don't understand why `sublist[index] = …` works, but `element = …` doesn't, you may want to make this even more explicit:

```
for outer_index, sublist in enumerate(data):
    for inner_index, element in enumerate(sublist):
```

… and then set `data[outer_index][inner_index] = …`.

There are a lot of ways you can improve this. For one thing, `int(1)` is guaranteed to be the same thing as `1`. For another, you could simplify this whole thing with `sublist[index] = int(element) + (1 if index % 2 == 0 else -1)`. And, once you've got the logic right, you can figure out a way to do this immutably—building a new list instead of changing the list in-place, which then opens the door to more simplifications, like turning the whole loop into a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

So heres one method:

```
w = [[str(int(y)+(-1,1)[i%2]) for i,y in enumerate(x)] for x in w]
```

basically you just iterate over the lists, and then iterate over the elements of each list, adding / subtracting 1 depending on `x%2` (odd / even).

Since this is done in a list constructor or two, the lists are rebuilt as they are iterated over.